# How to switch tab in web application

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events, keyboard

I am developing a web application, I need to use keyboard to open/switch tabs in following ways,

1. When I press ctrl + alt + 1 tab1 should open.
2. But without releasing ctrl and alt if I press 2 tab2 should open.

I am able to achieve 1 and 2 but with releasing ctrl and alt keys.

Comment: This is not my exact code, but my code works simillar  

var keys = '';  
$(document).keydown(function (e) {  
    keys += e.which;  
});  

$(document).keyup(function (e) {  
if(keys == "171849")  
$("#Tab1").click();  
else if(keys == "171850")  
$("#Tab2").click();  

keys="";  
});

Comment: Is this necessary to open the tab1 before tab2?

Comment: No i can open anyone randomly :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the way you have used to find the pressed keys is not good when it has ctrl & alt. You can simply listen for the `ctrl+alt+1` and `ctrl+alt+2` like this,

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.altKey) {
        // 97 for key "1"
        if (e.keyCode == 97) {
            // open first tab
            $("#Tab1").click();
        }
        else if (e.keyCode == 98) {
            // 98 for key "2"
            // open second tab
            $("#Tab2").click();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: vote up and accept the answer if it helps! If it doesn't work, what is the issue you have faced on this code?

Comment: Worked!!!!!!!
Thank you very much. Hope it works well if i modify the code by switch instead of if cos i have many key events to work with.

Thanks anyways, Helped a lot